# access webservice over local network

Tags: web-services, iis, networking

i have a webservice on a computer with windows 7 hosted using IIS and i can access it using the link

```
http://localhost/election_service/service.asmx
```

i have another computer that connected with the first one using only a switch and every computer has an ip for the first has 192.168.1.219 and the second has 192.168.1.3

i want to access the web service on the second computer

on the first computer when i tried to access the webservice and replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.219 as

```
 http://192.168.1.219/election_service/service.asmx
```

it failed so how can i make it accessible so i can access it from the second computer using this link

Comment: on which computer you have your server - 3 or 219?